# Making an incomplete IF statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I am making a small dungeon crawler text game and there is a certain code I want to use, but i can't figure out how. I want to create an IF statement that has an incomplete end statement.

```
if cmd.lower() == "examine ...":
```

the three dots will be anything the user chooses. The number of options are too great to have that many IF statements for every single one. Is there anyways that I can just take the "Examine" part of their input and use that in an IF statement?

Comment: `cmd.lower().startswith("examine ")`, perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to "tokenise" your input string, then "dispatch" the result based on the command, i.e., the first token.

You might explore a solution like this:

```
def examine(thing):
    print(f'It is a {thing}')

def attack(target):
    print(f'You strike {target}.  It seems offended.')

def tokenise_input(inp):
    command, *args = inp.split(' ')

    return (command, args)

def dispatch(command, *args):
    commands = {
        'examine': examine,
        'kill': attack,
        'attack': attack,
        ...,
    }

    return commands[command](*args)

command, args = tokenise_input(cmd)

dispatch(command, *args)
```

I'm sure you can imagine expanding the `commands` dictionary to allow for more commands the user can use, each pointing to their own function.

The above syntax for string interpolation, `f'...'` is new in 3.6, and will cause a syntax error in earlier versions.  I recommend you use 3.6, 'cause it's awesome, but if you can't, substitute such usages like so:

```
def examine(thing):
    print('It is a {thing}'.format(thing=thing))
```

Comment: Woah, what's that `print(f"{thing}"` syntax called? Never seen that before!

Comment: That is an excellent example of adopting good scalable practices.

Comment: f -sring is called literal string interpolation,  new since Python 3.6: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/ and yes it is super exciting

Comment: I'll update the answer to point out f-strings are new, and how to use not-f-strings.

Comment: How would I put it so if the input is not in the dictionary, the command is skipped and gives a given message? I can't figure out where I would put it for it to work efficiently. I probably could do it, but very messily. At the current moment, if I type something not in the dictionary, the whole thing crashes.